# Setting background of GVim

Tags: vim

I am working with dark background in both Vim an GVim. However, in the GVim the dark background is not loaded automatically (through `.vimrc`), but stays `light` and I need to set it automtically for every session. See the screenshots below.

**Loading a file in Vim:**

[image]

**Loading a file in GVim:**

[image]

**Executing `set background=dark` after loading a file in GVim (note that `set background=dark` is indeed in my `.vimrc`):**

[image]

What can cause this problem?

Comment: Without your vimrc we can't answer anything.

Comment: The `background` option doesn't change the background color.

Comment: @romainl What does it do? It did solve the problem though.

Comment: Try adding `set background=dark` in `~/.gvimrc` (create one if not exist).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As romainl already indicates, the `background` option tells Vim what the background color looks like. You could enable the background to dark with the syntax higlighting. As it seems, you're using a GUI. So consider the following in your .vimrc:

`hi Normal guifg=grey guibg=black`

`hi` stands for higihglighting. And guifg and guibg stands for, as you probably already guessed it, for GUI foreground and background colors.

Comment: I think 'hi CursorLine' required too.